# How to relocate or resize items using mouse in Intellij Idea scene builder?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

I am using Intellij Idea scene builder. I am unable to resize or make relative designs using mouse. Whenever I try to place an item this happens: 
[image]

I can't resize items using mouse also. Here is the fxml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="300" prefWidth="500" xmlns="http://javafx.com /javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">

</AnchorPane>
```

Is there any issue or I am missing some code?

Comment: If you're unable to get IntelliJ's embedded Scene Builder to work, you can try using the [standalone Scene Builder application](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/).

Answer (score 1):

It's a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-198072). Please follow it for updates in YouTrack.