# Unable to move elements using cursor in IntelliJ's Scene Builder - any fix?

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

Essentially my issue is the same as the one found at this link, however, this was multiple years ago and no solution was presented: [How to relocate or resize items using mouse in Intellij Idea scene builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57150498/how-to-relocate-or-resize-items-using-mouse-in-intellij-idea-scene-builder)

I am using a Windows machine, with fresh installs of IntelliJ, the JavaSDK, and JavaFX.

However, I am unable to move or resize elements using the cursor within the Scene Builder; doing so just results in the cursor turning into a cross, much like in the above question.

I was wondering if anyone had found any solutions since the original question was asked?

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: Have you considered [this possible "solution"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57150498/how-to-relocate-or-resize-items-using-mouse-in-intellij-idea-scene-builder#comment100822517_57150498) (i.e., use the standalone version)?

Comment: As noted in the duplicate, it is a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-198072) in the implementation of SceneBuilder within Idea.  The known bug's status is currently unresolved.  The workaround is to use an [external SceneBuilder install](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/#download) instead of the SceneBuilder integration in Idea.

Comment: Check if the problem reproduces in 2022.3 IDE build from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download